# Проверка на валидность нескольких значений

Tags: java, android

Почему после такой проверки всегда `"you are  registered"`? Что не так?

```
if (!((isEmailValid(email) || (isPasswordValid(password)) || (isNameValid(name))))) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong email/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "\n" + "You are registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    return (email.contains("@") && email.length() > 5);
}

private boolean isNameValid(String name) {
    return name.length() >= 3;
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    return password.length() > 6;
}
```

Comment: Нет, не всегда будет `"You are registered"`. Если email, пароль и имя одновременно неверны, то будет `"Wrong email/password"`. Причем почему в этом тексте нет ни намёка на возможно неправильное имя - мне непонятно. Представьте каково будет пользователю, если он будет вводить корректные email и пароль, а ему будет выдаваться ошибка `"Wrong email/password"` из-за недопустимого имени.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы поставили в условие **или** (||) если хотя бы одно из них будет верно, выражение будет истинно + **отрицание** (!) (непонятно зачем). А вам нужно, чтобы всегда все 3 были верны для этого нужен оператор **и** (&&)

```
if (isEmailValid(email) && isPasswordValid(password) && isNameValid(name)) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "\n" + "You are registered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else  {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong email/password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
}
```

**P.S.** Для проверки E-mail лучше использовать что-то вроде этого:

```
public static final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(

            "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
                    + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                    + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
                    + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
                    + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
                    + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$");

public boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        return EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

Comment: Как работает этот патерн ?

Comment: По регулярному выражению проверяет email

Answer (score 2):

Согласно правилам математической логики,

```
!(a || b) == !a && !b
```

поэтому Ваше условие

```
!((isEmailValid(email) || (isPasswordValid(password)) || (isNameValid(name))))
```

эквивалентно следующему:

```
!isEmailValid(email) && !isPasswordValid(password) && !isNameValid(name)
```

То есть, оно срабатывает ***только если*** введены ошибочно ***одновременно*** e-mail, пароль и имя. Вероятно, Вам нужно отклонять пользователя, если он ввёл неправильно ***хотя бы одно***. Для этого условие должно быть следующим:

```
!isEmailValid(email) || !isPasswordValid(password) || !isNameValid(name)
```

Это условие сработает, если введён ошибочно ***хотя бы один*** параметр - e-mail, пароль или имя.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, со скобками ты намудрил, легко запутаться. А выдает потому как логику дал такую: если ХОТЬ ОДНА проверка поля валидная, то -- успешная регистрация. А, по-идее, нужно наоборот: если ВСЕ проверки валидны, то -- успешная регистрация. То есть вот так:
if ( !(isEmailValid(email) && isPasswordValid(password) && isNameValid(name)) ) {...